# Test card numbers for balanced payments

Tags: balanced-payments, balanced-groups

We are planning to integrate our website with balanced payment gateway, would like to know how can we test credit card transactions. Like to have list of test card numbers so that we can test all the card related scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

Test card numbers are listed in their documentation. https://docs.balancedpayments.com/1.1/overview/resources/#test-credit-card-numbers